# How to fetch gmail contacts using Google Api in android

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch gmail contacts list using google api but no.

I am adding all these scopes

```
.requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts"))
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read"))
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"))
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"))
                .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"))`
```

I am hitting get request to get response from the server

```
//String url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+personEmail+"/full";
```

String url ="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";

```
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d("response",response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("error",error!=null?error.getMessage():"unknown error");
                }
            }
            );
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-gmail-contacts-list-in-Android-app). You can do this using [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters). Contacts API allows client applications to view and update a user's contacts. This [link](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/tree/master/java/sample/contacts) will helpful to you to do your code.

Comment: i tried both of the links already but could not get anything complete..

Comment: @abielita have to tried to use the given library??